# Issue with REMOTE-SSH into vagrant using VSCode (Mac)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vagrant, vagrant-ssh

I am trying to follow this [link](https://medium.com/@lizrice/ssh-to-vagrant-from-vscode-5b2c5996bc0e) to try connecting into my vagrant vm box with VSCode in Mac Catalina.  But every time I am getting "could not establish connection with default".

The link said to copy the 'vagrant ssh-config' results to ~/.ssh/config. Before I did this, the ~/.ssh folder was empty.

The content of the config file copied from 'vagrant ssh-config' is as follows:

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/stewartty/udacity-courses/fullstack/vagrant/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL

Host vagrant
  HostName vagrant
  User vagrant
```

In VSCode, I installed the Remote-SSH extension.  Then I followed exactly to the word as laid out in the link (open command palette and select the ./ssh/config file AND again, open command palette and select 'Remote SSH: Connect to Host... and select 'Default').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a rookie mistake - I should have run `vagrant up` first before trying to `remote-ssh` using VSCode. I’ve had no problem remoting after running `vagrant up`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your vagrant IP.
most of the time has your `inet` range ip, to see the virtual machine

```
ifconfig | grep inet
```

Refer to the `Vagrantfile` network section

Comment: Looks like its just 127.0.0.1 - here's the `ifconfig | grep inet` results:
` inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
 inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
 inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
       . . .`

Comment: vagrant file location 
```vagrant ssh
```
in vm check ip address

Comment: `Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04-i386"
  config.vm.box_version = "= 2.3.5"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"`